# While finding escape velocity, does human mass counts as the mass of Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, earth, escape-velocity

Escape velocity depends upon the mass of earth. my doubt is whether human mass adds into it or not? If it add then Earth's escape velocity would be increasing!

Comment: Humans obey conservation of mass, so all their mass comes from eating things on Earth. We can not yet catch matter from outer space and eat it. Increasing population may decrease mineral fraction (and possibly plant, water) of mass of Earth, but not total mass of Earth.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you need to include the mass of the 7 billion or so humans in the total mass of the Earth, though since their total mass is something like $5 \times 10^{11}$kg and the mass of the Earth is around $6 \times 10^{24}$kg humans make up only about 0.00000000001% of the total mass. We don't make any great contribution to the escape velocity.

The point of your second sentence is presumably that as the number of humans increases their total mass increases. This is true, but humans are basically created from carbon dioxide and water (courtesy of plants) so an increase in the number of humans means a corresponding decrease in the mass of carbon dioxide and water. The total mass of the Earth + humans doesn't change.

Comment: Well it should, we're receiving Sun radiation that plants use to combine atoms into heavier particles. Thus there's some bond energy trapped there, which means more mass, right?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Indeed, but there is also the other direction, energy being radiated away from Earth. Either way, it is likely that Earth's total mass is not constant.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia: the mass change due to absorption or emission of radiation is negligible.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Photosynthesis is chemistry. In chemical reaction, the overall mass does not change. Energy is stored in chemical bonds, but that doesn't make the resulting molecules any more massive than the sum of their atoms.

Comment: A bigger factor of mass gain is the dust Earth receive every day from space. Estimates varie but range from 5 to 300 tons per day.

Comment: Earth's mass does change, but it has little to do with the population increase/decrease of humans.

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't need to account for the mass of humans. We're a part of the total mass. Children who grow and gain weight are merely transferring mass from other parts of the Earth to them. The mass of humanity versus the mass of everything else on the Earth is a zero sum game.

To see whether the Earth is changing mass, you need to look outside the box (or in this case, outside the Earth). Imagine a spherical boundary 10,000 kilometers above the surface of the Earth. Some stuff, mostly hydrogen, crosses that boundary from inside to outside. This represents mass lost to the universe. Other stuff, mostly tiny little meteorites, crosses that boundary from outside to inside. This represents mass gained from the universe.

The estimated loss in mass due to escaping hydrogen is estimated to be about 260 metric tons per day. The estimates in how much the Earth is gaining mass due to incoming meteorites and space dust vary widely, from a mere 5 metric tons per day to over 300 metric tons per day. The lower figure means the Earth loses about 255 metric tons of mass every day. The upper figure means the Earth gains about 40 metric tons per day.

Those numbers sound large, but compared to the total mass of the Earth, they are very small.

Answer (score 4):

There is approximately 7 billion people on earth. If we take some average of about 75 kg each, that means
$$
m_{\rm population}=7\cdot10^9\times75\,{\rm kg}=5.25\cdot10^{11}\,{\rm kg}
$$
The [mass of the earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mass) is roughly
$$
m_{\rm earth}=5.97\cdot10^{24}\,{\rm kg}
$$
which is about 13 [orders of magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) *bigger* than the total population of the world. So no, the population of earth is irrelevant to the escape velocity of earth.

Comment: We've both assumed that the average human is well fed :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie: Considering all the babies & children in the world, we probably should have low-balled it at around 60 kg (so $4.2\cdot10^{11}\,{\rm kg}$ total).